# Two different resutls of visualisation

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

My data looks like:

```
Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex
0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male
1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female
1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female
1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female
0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male
0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,
```

When I'm trying to compare the number of survivors in first class and the gender it is showing me weird results.

When I try do it like this

```
data[(data['Sex']=='female') & (data['Pclass']== 1)]['Survived'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')


plt.legend()
plt.xticks(np.arange(2), rotation=0)
plt.title("Male and female survivors in first class")

plt.show()
```

It shows that almost every female in first class did survive (and that is correct)

But when I try do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('titanic_data/train.csv')

males = data[(data['Sex']=='male') & (data['Pclass'] == 1)]['Survived'].value_counts()
females = data[(data['Sex']=='female') & (data['Pclass']== 1)]['Survived'].value_counts()

plt.bar(range(len(females)), females, align='edge', width=-0.4, label='Female', color='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.bar(range(len(males)), males, align='edge', width=0.4, label='Male', color='blue', alpha=0.5)


plt.legend()
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(males)), rotation=0)
plt.title("Male and female survivors in first class")

plt.show()
```

It shows that almost every female died (and that is wrong!)

The male results are correct.
[image: Correct]
[image: Not correct]

Comment: It works fine for me. I get 2 females as alive and 0 males alive. Try `print (females)` and you will see 2

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. I have 0 males and 2 females survived.

Comment: The problem is in the visualization I think. Add `plt.xticks(np.arange(4), rotation=0)` and you will see similar looking bar as you see for your `df.plot`

Comment: Use full data file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AbZ40V8klO6v6NPml2e5t_j2GDvQVFH4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I updated the question. After print(females) I see "1 - 94, 0 - 3". This is not what I see on my bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[matplotlib.pyplot.bar](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) takes x coordinate of bars but you are providing `range(len(females))`, which is just assigning 0,1 arbitrarily to the bar plot without looking at the order of `Survived` column in the output of `value_counts()`. What you want to provide for x coordinate is the index instead. For example:

```
plt.bar(females.index, females, align='edge', width=-0.4, label='Female', color='red', alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: Now it is working. But why "male" bar was displayed correct? I did it the same way as female.

Comment: output of `value_counts()` for male happened to be in the right order (0, 1). Probably because the value of 0 came first before 1, so it counted 0 first.